# Show Mailjet Permalink in Iframe on own page

Tags: mailjet

I have the client request to show the permalink-Version of a mailjet campaign inside the clients website. So instead of going to the standard online version mailjet provides, I need to pass this uri or some identifier to some page on the website. What I already tried is http://mywebsite.com/[[PERMALINK]] and it does exactly what it should, but as the permalink isn't url-encoded, this call breaks for sure.

Another idea would be to pass some campaign_id to the website and get the rest of the information from the api but where to get it from inside a template?

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm leading the API at Mailjet.
I understand your use-case and the issue you face. We do provide the online URL of a given campaign through the campaigndraft resource as documented [here](https://dev.mailjet.com/email-api/v3/campaigndraft/). However, it alone won't be enough for you to get the web version as the `[[PERMALINK]]` tag is generating (personalization tags will be there for instance).

The recipe to generate the full URL is not something we're willing to publish online.

Can you follow up by email at api at mailjet dot com to pursue this discussion in DM?

Thanks for having chosen Mailjet to power your email.