# Is it possible to get the online-version link of a campaign with mailjet api?

Tags: mailjet

I am thinking of creating an archive list of sent newsletters with mailjet. The easiest would be to get the online-version links and list them. But I didn't find getting the urls in the Documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show Mailjet Permalink in Iframe on own page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590500/show-mailjet-permalink-in-iframe-on-own-page)

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594121/

> However, it alone won't be enough for you to get the web version as the [[PERMALINK]] tag is generating (personalization tags will be there for instance).
> The recipe to generate the full URL is not something we're willing to publish online.